# Dependency error while resolving controller with autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac

I'm developing an ASP.MVC application. I use Autofac for DI. My controller PayrollCenterReportsController places at assembly 'LK.Reports.Services.WebApi.Module' and requires some serivce at constructor:

```
public class PayrollCenterReportsController : ODataControllerBase<PayrollCenterReports>
    {
        public PayrollCenterReportsController(IDataService<PayrollCenterReports> service)
            : base(service)
        {
        }
    }
```

I'm registering serivce at other assembly

```
public class MenaAutofacInitializer : IAutofacIntitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            ...

            builder.RegisterType<PayrollCenterReportsClientService>().As<IDataService<PayrollCenterReports>>();

            ...
        }
    }
```

and at Global.asax i use my initializer:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
new MenaAutofacInitializer().Initialize(builder);
var container = builder.Build();

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

SiteMaps.Loader = container.Resolve<ISiteMapLoader>();
```

But at page i get error:

> An error has occurred. 
>   An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'PayrollCenterReportsController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor. 
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>    at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()
>     An error has
>   occurred.  Type
>   'LK.Reports.Services.WebApi.Module.Controllers.PayrollCenterReportsController'
>   does not have a default constructor 
>   System.ArgumentException 
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) at
>   System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type
>   instanceType) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type
>   controllerType)

The only way to resolve it is to use assembly with controller explicitly:

```
var a = typeof (PayrollCenterReportsController)
```

With this code Autofac resolve dependency and all fine.

loading assembly

```
assembly = Assembly.Load("LK.Reports.Services.WebApi.Module, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
```

didn't help

Is there any way to resolve it without explitly using typeof(PayrollCenterReportsController) in Global.asax?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid explicitly registering all you controllers you can use the    `RegisterControllers` method

```
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
```

which can take more than one assembly :

```
builder.RegisterControllers(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

You can find more information in the documentation : [Register Controllers](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#register-controllers)

---

By the way, instead of your custom `IAutofacIntitializer` interface I recommend using `IModule`. See [documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/modules.html) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar error on my way to getting OData into an MVC5 project. The following steps helped me to get it up and running:

1. Use the Autofac.WebApi2 nuget package, not the Autofac.WebApi package. (And uninstall Autofac.WebApi before adding WebApi2, this will save you from manually adding WebApi2 to the references.)
2. Add a reference to the WebApi2 extensions in your Global.asax.cs (or wherever you're spinning up Autofac) with `using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;`
3. MVC and WebApi use separate DI frameworks. For MVC, register your controllers with `builder.RegisterControllers`. For WebApi2 (OData) use `builder.RegisterApiControllers`.
4. Finally, set your DI resolvers, one for MVC and one for WebApi2:

   `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container)); // MVC`

   `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container); // WebApi2`